# Combining genetic algorithm with local optimization

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, heuristics, hybrid, genetic

I am generally interested in combining genetic algorithms with some local optimization and use this approach to do railway scheduling optimization. I would appreciate if someone could lead me to resources or examples in this Topic as I couldn't find relevant Information in the internet yet. There was a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350837/how-to-mix-genetic-algorithm-with-some-heuristic)

Comment: Topic sounds interesting, but it is too broad what you are asking here, you would need to approach your question to a more concrete use case, or maybe you can get more feedback in another community,  focused on artificial intelligence, soft computing or machine learning